# GLX Vsync event

Tags: c, x11, framebuffer, epoll, glx

I'm wondering if I could catch the screen vsync event by any file descriptor and [select | poll | epoll]ing it.

Normally, if I'm right, glXSwapBuffers() doesn't block the process so I could do something like :

```
int init() {
    create epollfd;
    add Xconnection number to it;
    add some other fd like socket timer tty etc...
    possibly add a vsync fd like dri/card0 or fb0 or other???
    return epollfd;
}

main() {
    int run = 1;
    int epollfd = init();

    while(run) {
        epoll_wait(epollfd, ...) {

        if(trigedfd = socket) {
            do network computing;
        }

        if(trigedfd = timer) {
            do physics computing;
        }

        if(trigedfd = tty) {
            do electronic communications;
        }

        if(trigedfd = Xconnection number) {
            switch(Xevent) {
                case key event:
                    do key computing;
                case mouse event:
                    do mouse computing;
                case vsync???:
                    do GL computings;
                    glXSwapBuffers();
            }
        }

        if(trigedfd = dri/card0 or fb0 or other???) {
            do GL computings;
            glXSwapBuffers();
        }
    }
}
```

So I could then I could trig any event regardless when vsync event happen and avoid by the same time tearing effect in the case where I use only X drawing function and possibly GL for vsync.

Could libdrm help me? the more general question is :

So what fd do I have to use to catch vsync event and how to make shure on this fd that the event that happened is a vsync event?

Comment: Notice that I want to make it monothreaded.
I could make a separated process that acts like a server which I could connect to and send a request "wake me when vsync happened", this process could block on a glFinish and then send something via a socket or pipe or whatever, I would avoid it too.

Comment: Why exactly do you want this? Could this be a case of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: I'm creating my own library/api, I want to have only one sync point for all incomming events of a process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can use the libdrm API to see vsync events. See [this blog entry](https://dvdhrm.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/advanced-drm-mode-setting-api/), and in particular [this example code](https://github.com/dvdhrm/docs/blob/master/drm-howto/modeset-vsync.c). A comment from the code explains how it works:

```
/* (...)
 * The DRM_MODE_PAGE_FLIP_EVENT flag tells drmModePageFlip() to send us a
 * page-flip event on the DRM-fd when the page-flip happened. The last argument
 * is a data-pointer that is returned with this event.
 * (...)
 */
```

You need to set up a page-flip event handler to be notified when a vsync occurs, which will be called by the `drmHandleEvent` method (from libdrm) which you can call when there is activity on the drm file descriptor.

However, mapping all this into an X client might prove difficult or impossible. It *may* be that you can open the drm device yourself and just listen for vsync events (without attempting to set the mode etc), but this might also prove impossible. Pertinent code:

```
drmEventContext ev;
memset(&ev, 0, sizeof(ev));
ev.version = DRM_EVENT_CONTEXT_VERSION;
ev.page_flip_handler = modeset_page_flip_event;

// When file descriptor input is available:
drmHandleEvent(fd, &ev);
// If above works, "modeset_page_flip_event" will be called on vertical refresh.
```

The problem is that a page flip event only seems to be generated if you have actually issued a page flip (buffer swap) request. Presumably it would be the X server that issued such requests, but it doesn't even necessarily flag that it wants to be notified when the vsync actually occurs (i.e. uses the `DRM_MODE_PAGE_FLIP_EVENT` flag).

There's also the difficulty of opening the correct dri device (`/dev/dri/card0` or `/dev/dri/card1` or ...?)

Given the difficulty/unreliability/general unworkability of all the above, the easiest solution is probably to:

1. Use a separate thread to wait for vsync using standard GL calls. According to [this page on the OpenGL wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Swap_Interval) you should use `glXSwapIntervalEXT(1)` to enable vsync, then `glXSwapBuffers` and `glFinish` to ensure that the vertical retrace actually occurs.
2. Then, notify the main thread that vertical retrace occurred. You can do this by sending data to a pipe or, on Linux, use an `eventfd`.

**Update**:

You may be able to use the [GLX_INTEL_swap_event extension](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/INTEL/GLX_INTEL_swap_event.txt):

> Accepted by the  parameter of glXSelectEvent and returned in the  parameter of glXGetSelectedEvent:
>
> GLX_BUFFER_SWAP_COMPLETE_INTEL_MASK 0x04000000
>
> Returned in the <event_type> field of a "swap complete" event:
>
> GLX_EXCHANGE_COMPLETE_INTEL       0x8180
> GLX_COPY_COMPLETE_INTEL           0x8181
> GLX_FLIP_COMPLETE_INTEL           0x8182

...

> A client can ask to receive swap complete GLX events on a window.
> When an event is received, the caller can determine what kind of swap occurred by checking the event_type field.

This means that, if the extension is supported, you can receive swap notifications (which correspond to vertical retrace if vsync is enabled) via regular X events, which you'll see on the X connection file descriptor.

Comment: I've already seen this blog and code, I tryed to launch modeset as is, it said to me "drm device /dev/dri/card0 does not support dumb buffers".
I've only /dev/dri/card0.

I've not tryed more on drm side for the moment, I was wondering that was possible via X11 extensions...

Comment: @LewisAnesa you don't need dumb buffers. You don't need to map a buffer at all; you just need to receive events (page flip event). The only open question is whether these events will indeed be delivered.

Comment: Yes, I'll continue these investigations after work (french time zone), perhaps activating v-sync via glXSwapIntervalEXT(1) induces these event to be delivered by dri device..?

I haven't seen any documents for libdrm such as the xlib documentation, if you see something, feel free to share.

Comment: Ough... I used https://fossies.org/dox/mesa-demos-8.3.0/glxgears_8c_source.html to make test and add time watch around glXSwapBuffers(dpy, win); line 342 and then, surprise!!! glXSwapBuffers blocks during around 16ms. notice that glXQueryExtensionsString(dpy, scrnum); line 585 doesn't return any swap extension.
So I guess I can't double buffer or get vsync...

Comment: Hmm. It may turn out that the only real option is to use threads (i.e. do your `glXSwapBuffers` call in a separate thread and signal the main thread somehow when it is done).

Comment: Yes it seems to take this way, so I have to make a thread for each window hosting a gl port view since glXSwapBuffers is window attached and communicate with a pipe to each trhead I guess. Then I can take these pipes in epollfd... @davmac, If you want to add some lines on your post about this or another solution...

Comment: @LewisAnesa Done, but see also recent revision.

Comment: Revision checked... It looks like this extension won't be able on arm procs such as raspberry pi, or other...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, from looking all over the web for extensions and interfaces to poll vsync <sub>[1]</sub>, I've found the best (least-resource intensive) method that is likely to be available is the following:

1. Query vtrace rate (every 16.666ms for a 60hz monitors).
2. `nanosleep` some portion of that delay (say 15ms) depending on the querying accuracy and the expected variance of the vsync pulse.
3. `clock_gettime` our remaining time-quota and (optionally) do some real-time computing if we can. Typically computation should be done at step 7.
4. Busy-wait for vsync using one of the methods noted below. Add `pause` instructions.
5. Immediately `clock_gettime` to ensure accurate sleep delay on next cycle.
6. Do drawing or pixel-querying.
7. Do any other computations, use threading, watchdogs or real-time computing.
8. Repeat step 2.

You could dynamically increase the delay time if you trust your own code (But be too agressive and you start dropping frames).
If you really need a reliable poll and can't spinlock at all, you can do all this in another thread. The `nanosleep` should ensure the kernel doesn't schedule your thread for most of its lifetime.

You'll have to calibrate the delay but you can probably eyeball it. 15ms is extremely conservative and pretty much guaranteed to work.
The querying method I use results in a variance of around 16.665-16.667, so any delay below that should be enough.
It all depends on how much you trust your `nanosleep` implementation and your thread scheduler. Use a real-time scheduling policy if your kernel supports it (Or don't worry about any of this, take the easy way out and busy-wait like everyone else).

This is the method most screen-recorders are using.

## Querying Vblank frequency

If your driver supports it, you can call `glXGetVideoSyncSGI` (from the `GLX_SGI_video_sync` extension) repeatedly and time with `clock_gettime` to query vblank rate (e.g. 16.666ms).
Alternatives to finding vsync rate are `glXGetSwapIntervalMESA` and `glXQueryDrawable(dpy, drawable, GLX_SWAP_INTERVAL_EXT, &interval)` (from `GLX_MESA_swap_control` and `GLX_EXT_swap_control` respectively). Benefits of `GLX_SGI_video_sync` are that you only need one extension (see next section).

`glXGetSyncValuesOML` from the `GLX_OML_sync_control` extension returns the same counter, but is probably less efficient because it has to fetch other irrelevant values. It might potentially return a more accurate vsync rate. It's also not available on my system, so I don't know how portable it is.

## Waiting for Vsync

You can set a timer after each frame for say ~15ms after the start of the current frame (Use `clock_nanosleep` and non-relative time if you can), and then busy-wait the rest until the `glXGetVideoSyncSGI` counter changes value. Connecting the timer to a poll/event loop should then be trivial.

You could maybe do some real-time computing inside the busy loop if you're brave enough.

`glXWaitForMscOML` from `GLX_OML_sync_control` does the same thing and might have some optimizations, but it's not available on my system and I wouldn't be surprised if it is just busy-waiting like everything else. I also don't know how reliable it is. There are most certainly other methods to wait for vsync too (MESA/DRM/KMS), but they are even less portable than `GLX_SGI_video_sync`, and once again, they typically busy-wait.

Even if no frame counter is available, you could assume that `glXSwapBuffers` blocks and still do something similar (Note that on all drivers I know of, users may turn off the blocking behaviour manually. Check out `GLX_EXT_swap_control` to try and override this behaviour). At this point it might just be better to loop calling `glXSwapBuffers` in another thread, though.

If all else fails, you can busy-wait on `clock_gettime` instead. `nanosleep` used to do this, but nowadays you have to do it yourself. If you're using this method, you should probably hardcode well-known vsync values instead of relying on querying (any variance in sleep delay might result in dropped frames, that said vsync has natural variance anyway due to the asynchronous nature of the hardware so reliable vsync without driver support might be impossible).

The "compton" open-source compositor manager mentions the following methods to wait for `vsync`:

- `DRM_IOCTL_WAIT_VBLANK`

Linux-specific.
Very reliable for waiting, also doesn't require OpenGL.
Properly suspends thread instead of busy-waiting.
Unfortunately, `_DRM_VBLANK_SIGNAL` is not implemented and `_DRM_VBLANK_EVENT` is broken, so a blocking wait is still the only valid use-case.
DRM actually *does* give accurate vsync pulses for applications that manually swap buffers, but this can hardly be called `lightweight`. Also, if you're swapping buffers anyway, you might as well just use `glXSwapBuffers`.
Recommended if you need high performance and don't care about portability.

- `SGI_video_sync`

Cross-platform. Almost universally available. This is what I recommend.

- `OML_sync_control`

Recommended if it's available.

- `EXT_swap_control`
- `SGI_swap_control`
- `MESA_swap_control`

I would not recommend this. This is the `glXSwapBuffers` approach. Most drivers support this, but it's also resource-intensive and prone to break if driver settings change. Most of these implementations spinlock.

## Conclusion

Unfortunately, it seems like there won't be a resource-friendly way to poll vsync anytime soon. The video driver clearly has to keep track of vsync to know when to send the next frame, so there's no technical reason why there is no easy interface to poll vsync pulse available anywhere, but unfortunately, consensus from linux, nvidia and khronos seems to be "nobody needs this".

Typically vtrace pulses are very important for pixel querying (case point: literally every compositor manager ever has a bug report or mail-list thread about vsync), but it also has uses for real-time computing.

[1] vsync a.k.a. vtrace a.k.a. buffer swap a.k.a. frame counter increment a.k.a. frame round-trip