# How to obtain the VSync Display refresh pulse in Linux?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, vsync

I'm programming some routines on a Linux NASM x86-64 asm code.

How can I obtain the pulse of the display refresh, VSync?

I guess maybe via syscall I can reach the pulse, but I accept other suggestions, don't ask me why, i really need the pulse to avoid Flicker on display.

I know how to do it for windows as shown in code below, but Linux doesn't support D3D.

```
;;;;; WINDOWS VERSION EXAMPLE!
;ENABLE VSYNC
Therraszeta3:
CMP BYTE [RY_X+0x1003],255
jnz .L1232321
mov rcx,0
mov rax, [GetDC__]
mov [D3DKMT_OPENADAPTERFROMHDC_hDc], rax
lea rcx, [D3DKMT_OPENADAPTERFROMHDC]
call [GetProcAddress_LoadLibrary_Gdi32_dll_D3DKMTOpenAdapterFromHdc_]
mov [D3DKMTOpenAdapterFromHdc__], rax
;;
mov eax, dword [D3DKMT_OPENADAPTERFROMHDC_hAdapter]
mov dword [D3DKMT_WAITFORVERTICALBLANKEVENT_hAdapter], eax
mov dword [D3DKMT_WAITFORVERTICALBLANKEVENT_hDevice],0
mov eax, dword [D3DKMT_OPENADAPTERFROMHDC_VidPnSourceId]
mov dword [D3DKMT_WAITFORVERTICALBLANKEVENT_VidPnSourceId], eax
lea rcx, [D3DKMT_WAITFORVERTICALBLANKEVENT]
call [GetProcAddress_LoadLibrary_Gdi32_dll_D3DKMTWaitForVerticalBlankEvent_]
mov [D3DKMTWaitForVerticalBlankEvent__], rax
.L1232321
;;;;;
```

I expect to obtain the pulse in an infinite loop, indicating the beginning of every frame.

Comment: Which library do you use to do graphics on Linux?

Comment: What graphics stack is your Linux machine running?  traditional X11?  Wayland?  Console terminal in text mode or a framebuffer?  There's no one magic way; find a way in C and compile that to asm with an optimizing compiler.  And yes it will involve a system call because you're running in user-space; using `iopl` for `in`/`out` instructions isn't going to be helpful because you can't assume legacy VGA or set up your own interrupt handlers.

Comment: This is not really an asm question. Anyway, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36888778/547981)

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the source of a video player, e.g. `mpv` attempts to be a high-quality as possible for frame-timing (and color rendering).  https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/199aabddcc0105b504cc8e0cb240bc3c89288c1a/video/out/opengl/context_glx.c#L229 has a block of comments about how it uses GLX to get the time since last vsync.  It has other video-out drivers for other graphics stacks....  If you just want to sleep until right after a vsync, that's probably easier.

Comment: @PeterCordes, both purposes libX11 and terminal in syscall sys_write.

Comment: @Jester, thks for the tip.

Comment: @PhillipKrüger How do you do graphics in a terminal with just `write` calls?  Do you open a framebuffer device or something?

Comment: On terminal i don't do that, only create a thread to write to the buffer on a infinite loop, then i get the actual realtime size of the buffer, row and col,  and , wow the code is big, there's a lot of features, but the purpose is that it is refreshed with an secondary thread whose performs a BIT_BLK of a secondary buffer to the main one, relative to the screen display refresh, so when i clear the terminal it flickers, and, if i don't clear, the image get's unstable.